# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'recommend' on <module '__main__' from '/home/budhathoki/PycharmProjects/Recommendation_api/main.py'>

Tags: python, flask, pickle

I search for the solution and got nothing. Tried different ways but still got the same error.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
# filename = 'recommend.pkl'
# model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
with open('recommend.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)


@app.route('/recommendation', methods=['POST'])
def recommendation():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cuisine = request.form['cuisine']
        result = model.predict(cuisine)
        print(result)

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is there any class or function named `recommend` which is on other file or module which is used within the model which you have pickled ?

Comment: yes. I have made a function called recommend and pickled it

Comment: Import the function `recommend` into the current file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `recommend` function into `main.py`. Don't delete the python file that has 'recommend' function declared. I've faced with a similar issue after deleting the python file from which I made a pickle file. After restoring it worked fine